# Understanding Multi-Tenancy in Azure Active Directory (AD)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, multi-tenant

Here is a summary of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a regular Azure AD (not B2C) tenant... let's call it Hybrid.  I want to let non-Corpo users sign up/register accounts in that tenant by entering their name, email, company, etc.

I also want to let users in one other organization/tenant (call it Corpo) sign into Hybrid's tenant applications & show up as either a guest or external user in the Hybrid tenant, so I can manage their groups specifically within the Hybrid tenant.

I'm not doing a B2C tenant for this because it doesn't seem to adequately support app roles & I'm trying to accomplish setting up roles & permissions for all users in the Hybrid tenant.

Is this even doable without a B2C tenant?  I've figured out one way to let a Corpo user sign into a Hybrid-tenant app, but that user account doesn't show up in the users list then.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to let non-Corpo users sign up/register accounts in that tenant
> by entering their name, email, company, etc.

Only the administrator of the Corpo tenant can create users in the Corpo tenant. If you want users who are not the Corpo tenants to be added to the Corpo tenant, then you should [invite them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal) in instead of registering them in the tenant.

> I also want to let users in one other organization/tenant (call it
> Corpo) sign into Hybrid's tenant applications & show up as either a
> guest or external user in the Hybrid tenant, so I can manage their
> groups specifically within the Hybrid tenant.

When you set the hybrid tenant application as a multi-tenant application, then users from the Corpo tenant will be able to log in to the multi-tenant application. However, please note that even if a user of the Corpo tenant can log in to the application of the Hybrid tenant, the user will not appear as a guest or external user in the Hybrid tenant. Just like the previous question, you must [add the user of the Corpo tenant as a guest to the Hybrid tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal), then he will be displayed in the Hybrid tenant.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't want to add any users to the Corpo tenant.  Just be able to add Corpo users to the Hybrid tenant.  Thought maybe that could be done with self-sign up userflow rather than adding them as a guest manually.

Answer (score 0):

Carl is absolutely correct, you do have to add the Corpo tenant users as guests to your Hybrid tenant, but there are couple of ways to ease the management overhead of inviting them all. You can use [Entitlement Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-external-users) in the Hybrid tenant to let Corpo users request access for themselves (and you can delegate approval to someone else, like the manager or lead for each team.) It doesn't automagically add the Corp users to the Hybrid tenant over time, but it does allow you to send out notifications to your Corp users that they can [request access via a self-service portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-settings).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34399289)